# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1 in recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, android-recyclerview

I am using a recycler view.
Here is the adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<Contact> myContacts;
private Activity activity;

public MyAdapter(List<Contact> contacts,Activity activity)
{
    this.myContacts = contacts;
    this.activity = activity;
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ImageView mColorView;
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;
    public ViewHolder(View v,MyAdapter adapter) {
        super(v);
        mTextView =  v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        mColorView = v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        linearLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.listItemLinearLayout);
        v.setOnLongClickListener(onLongClickListener(myContacts.get(getAdapterPosition()).getID(),getAdapterPosition(),adapter));
    }
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v,this);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String name = myContacts.get(position).getName();
    TextDrawable myDrawable = TextDrawable.builder().beginConfig()
            .textColor(Color.WHITE)
            .useFont(Typeface.DEFAULT)
            .toUpperCase()
            .endConfig()
            .buildRound(name.substring(0,1),myContacts.get(position).getColor());

    holder.mColorView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
    holder.mTextView.setText(myContacts.get(position).getName());
    holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

}

private View.OnLongClickListener onLongClickListener(final long position, final int pos,final MyAdapter adapter){
    return new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setMessage("Delete item?");
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    LockedContacts.deleteTitle(position,activity);
                    myContacts.remove(pos);
                    notifyItemRemoved(pos);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, myContacts.size());
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert11 = alertDialog.create();
            alert11.show();

            return true;
        }
    };
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d("SIZE",String.valueOf(myContacts.size()));
    return myContacts.size();
}}
```

I am getting IndexOutofBoundException although I have not inserted any item in the list.

Here is the error:

```
Process: com.example.ark.AccessibilityService, PID: 17104                                                                                  
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
at com.example.ark.access.MyAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(MyAdapter.java:46)
at com.example.ark.access.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:57)
at com.example.ark.access.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:27)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6493)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5680)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5443)
at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:869)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5443)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5443)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5443)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5443)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5443)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5443)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2733)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16668)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5443)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6042)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackReco
```

It was working fine when the dialog box to delete item was in MainActivity, but I had to reload the activity to show that an item had been deleted.Now this error appears whenever the MainActivity starts. Can anyone tell me if there is any other way in which I can set a longOnClickListener on recycler view item which displays a dialog box,which deletes the item from the list on clicking OK and also reflects that the item has been deleted in the MainActivity?

Comment: Looks like `getAdapterPosition()` returns -1

Comment: Should I call getAdapterPosition() in the OnLongClick method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem in this line .

```
v.setOnLongClickListener(onLongClickListener(myContacts.get(getAdapterPosition()).getID(),getAdapterPosition(),adapter));
```

You are using `getAdapterPosition()` in constructor thats why its throwing -1.
Instead of it you can implements  `onLongClickListener` in your Holder class .

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener {
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ImageView mColorView;
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;
    public ViewHolder(View v,MyAdapter adapter) {
        super(v);
        mTextView =  v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        mColorView = v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        linearLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.listItemLinearLayout);
        v.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if(getAdapterPosition()!=-1) {
            // Do your stuff here
            onLongClickListener(myContacts.get(getAdapterPosition()).getID(), getAdapterPosition(), adapter)
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just implemented the Onclicklistener in the ViewHolder constructor and called getAdapterPosition() in OnLongClick()

Comment: @ADM I have a similar use case and crash here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74324524/android-crash-from-indexoutofboundsexception-length-36-index-1.  I would appreciate any thoughts or insights that you could provide for a fix.