# onActivityResult should call super.onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-studio, error-handling

I am new to Android Studio and trying to create a simple app. The app keeps crashing, when I need to save the data from the other activities, using onActivityResult:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Job updatedJobDetails = (Job)data.getSerializableExtra("updatedJobDetails");
            int position = data.getIntExtra("pos", -1);

            adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
            adapter.insert(updatedJobDetails, position);
        }
    }
}
```

First it says, that I need to

> onActivityResult should call super.onActivityResult

but when I do that, it crashes as soon as I use the method. Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.smapassignment01, PID: 6809
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.smapassignment01/com.example.smapassignment01.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=-1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=-1
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:393)
    at com.example.smapassignment01.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:122)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4353)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6809 SIG: 9
Process 6809 terminated.

I can't really read from the logcat-report, what I've done wrong.

According to [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904377/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-length-12-index-1-in-recyclerview-ad) it is because of getAdapterPosition - but I don't even use it, so I'm completely lost and have now used several hours, stuck.

UPDATE:

Just to show, that my pos has been sat in the other activity, from where the app crashes:

```
        btnSaveNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            job.setUserNotes(etJobNotes.getText().toString());


            if (!cbAppliedJob.isChecked()){
                job.setJobApplied(false);
            }
            else{
                job.setJobApplied(true);
            }
            Intent data = new Intent();
            position = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", -1);
            data.putExtra("pos", position);
            data.putExtra("updatedJobDetails", job);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `data.getIntExtra("pos", -1)` returned -1 because `pos` was not available. Therefore the `getItem` function throws the exception. This could have many causes. Maybe you have forgotten to set the `pos` extra?

Comment: Hi @Jannik - thanks for the quick reply. I've updated my question, showing that I do set the pos extra.

Comment: But have you checked that the value of `positition` is not `-1`? Because if the Intent returned by `getIntent()` in the second code snippet has no `pos` extra the value is still `-1`

Comment: @Jannik I've checked and it is -1, but isn't it suppose to be that? That's the value I give it in the other Activity as shown in the updated question. And if not - then what is wrong?

Comment: @Jannik I guess - from what I can read - that it should be 0? But then again, it just leaves me from where I started - not knowing, what is wrong..

Comment: If the value is `-1` then the `getItem()` function throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. That's not what you want, therefore you must handle the case where there is no/a negative position.
First you should think about what it means if the value is -1. You cannot remove an item which is not there in the first place, so it doesn't help to just set the value to 0. This would only remove another item which you might want to keep. The thing is, I cannot help you with this because I don't know what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: @Jannik Just wanted to say that it was a putExtra, that wasn't spelled right another place in the code. I don't understand, why it does not give any error-message then, which I am used to when writing c# in visual studio + using reSharper.. This is very specific and caused by a stupid error by me. Don't know if it is better to delete the question or let it be for others that might run into the same problem as me => check your putextras..